# Broken package? Libpam-runtime preventing kernel update

Tags: package-management

Long time reader first time poster. I think I am dealing with a broken package of libpam-runtime, which stalls kernel updates.

When doing update and upgrade I am told I need to configure packages

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
...
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Then I run the recommended command but the process seems to hang indefinitely.

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
...
Setting up libpam-runtime (1.3.1-5ubuntu4.1) ...
```

I try `sudo apt-get install libpam-runtime` but it hangs up dpkg forever and I can't use any more commands, saying `dpkg: error: dpkg frontend lock is locked by another process`  and I can't <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> out of it either.

So after a reboot I try to remove the troublesome package to install it again.

```
$ sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libpam-runtime
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of libpam-runtime:
 login depends on libpam-runtime.
 libpam-systemd:amd64 depends on libpam-runtime (>= 1.0.1-6).
 libpam-gnome-keyring:amd64 depends on libpam-runtime (>= 1.0.1-6).
 libpam-cap:amd64 depends on libpam-runtime (>= 1.1.3-2~).
 cron depends on libpam-runtime (>= 1.0.1-11).

dpkg: error processing package libpam-runtime (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libpam-runtime
```

I even downloaded the package from Ubuntu packages website and tried to install it from a local file instead but the process seems to hang somewhere again indefinitely.

```
$ sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/libpam-runtime_1.3.1-5ubuntu4.1_all.deb
Selecting previously unselected package libpam-runtime.
(Reading database ... 316308 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpam-runtime_1.3.1-5ubuntu4.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libpam-runtime (1.3.1-5ubuntu4.1) over (1.3.1-5ubuntu4.1) ...
Setting up libpam-runtime (1.3.1-5ubuntu4.1) ...
```

When I cancel the process and try my luck to upgrade it gets stuck indefinitely on libpam-runtime

```
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up libpam-runtime (1.3.1-5ubuntu4.1) ...
     

Progress: [  0%] [...............................] ..
```

Anything that can help me out? I'm using KDE Plasma on Ubuntu 20.04.

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpam-runtime

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done 

The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required: libnvidia-compute-440 
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it. 
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 116 not upgraded. 1 not fully installed or removed. After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used. 

E: Internal Error, No file name for libpam-runtime:amd64
```

Edit:
Per a request in the comment, I checked logs for dpkg and the output came out as follows.

```
$ dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
+++-=============================================-=======================================-============-======================================================================================================
iF  libpam-runtime                                1.3.1-5ubuntu4.1                        all          Runtime support for the PAM library
hi  libphonon4qt5-4:amd64                         4:4.11.1+p18.04+git20191211.0121-0      amd64        multimedia framework from KDE using Qt 5 - core library
ic  libsensors4:amd64                             1:3.4.0-4                               amd64        library to read temperature/voltage/fan sensors
hi  plasma-pa                                     4:5.18.3-0ubuntu1                       amd64        Plasma 5 Volume controller
ht  ufw                                           0.36-1ubuntu6                           all          program for managing a Netfilter firewall
```

Answer (score 2):

So I found a workaround on social media, the one thing I hardly ever check. The answer is to edit the file `/var/lib/dpkg/info/libpam-runtime.postinst` and comment the parts of the script starting where the command pam-auth-update package is executed all the way to the bottom of the function.

Then it's a simple matter of running `dpkg --configure -a` and then the process completes.

Thank you everyone for your time and your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

I am real newbie and I had the same problem as Sarcasmo!

I use "Nitrux 1.3.0 build.270620" UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal

Just read Zanna's solution and applied it.

These are the lines of the script in the file `libpam-runtime.postinst` that I comment it:

```
#pam-auth-update --package $force

#if [ -n "$force" ]; then
#       rm -f /etc/pam.d/common-auth.pam-old \
#             /etc/pam.d/common-account.pam-old \
#             /etc/pam.d/common-password.pam-old \
#             /etc/pam.d/common-session.pam-old
#elif dpkg --compare-versions "$2" lt-nl 1.1.0-1 \
#        && [ ! -e /etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive ]
#then
#       cp -a /etc/pam.d/common-session /etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive
#fi
```

after that I runned `dpkg --configure -a`

And it worked!

Thank you for your time and suggestion!